# Bootstrap themed dropdown menu failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a simple app using jQuery and Bootstrap. I'm having trouble adding dropdown menus. I've been trying to use the example code from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/ but it doesn't look like it works. Here's the code pretty much exactly the way it appears in the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Bootstrap Dropdown Theme Fail</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--  Bootstrap theme CSS -->    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dropdown menus</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown theme-dropdown clearfix">
        <a id="dropdownMenu1" href="#" class="sr-only dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see that, when you run this, all you get is the expanded dropdown list sitting on the page. No button, no activity, etc. Am I the only one that is seeing this behavior? Why doesn't this work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume because the code was being used on a display page they were showing how it looks instead of functions. Removing "theme-dropdown clearfix" from `<div class="dropdown theme-dropdown clearfix">` and removing the "sr-only" on `<a>` tag it can work as its coded now.

There is also an example on w3schools using a button and may be easier to get going. [w3schools dropdown](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Bootstrap Dropdown Theme Fail</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--  Bootstrap theme CSS -->    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dropdown menus</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a id="dropdownMenu1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I think they need should comment the examples to indicate that they are "for display only" and not actual working code.

Comment: Your example works exactly as it is shown on the page :)  In the navbar examples they show working dropdowns as well (yes they are in a navbar but that doesn't make much difference).

Answer (score 0):

Your Dropdown button doesn't appear because it has the "sr-only" class on it.  This means it is strictly for screen readers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Bootstrap Dropdown Theme Fail</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--  Bootstrap theme CSS -->    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Dropdown menus</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown theme-dropdown clearfix">
        <a id="dropdownMenu1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button now appears, but the menu is still just stuck on the screen. BTW - the 'sr-only' attribute is in the Bootstrap example code.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with this markup and works.

```
  <div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dropdownMenu1"  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvrrj47z/

Comment: yes you right.
try this fiddle i corrected the answer.